# Cannot convert template argument NULL to void*

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I've distilled a problem that's confounded me to the minimal example shown below. Basically the gcc compiler doesn't accept `NULL` as a template parameter of type `void*`.

Is there a workaround for this?

Please note that I'm restricted to C++03.

```
#define NULL 0

template<typename T = void , T* = NULL>
struct Foo
{
};

typedef Foo<> FooType;

int main()
{
}
```

Edit: [online version](http://rextester.com/WLJHKJ83334)

Comment: I don't see `NULL` there.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Fixed.

Comment: fyi g++ 5.1.0 (C++14) `error: could not convert template argument '0' to 'void*'`

Comment: No, it's not fixed, you can't use typedef  like that. Post some real code.

Comment: fyi2:  `typedef Foo<void, nullptr> FooType;` compiles. But `typedef Foo<void, 0> FooType;` does not

Comment: @RichardCritten I know. But I'm working on a C++03 codebase. That info is in the tag as well as the question body.

Comment: Changing the template line to: `template<typename T = void , T* = (T*)0>` compiles the original test.  I don't know why so this is not an answer.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes it does but not for C++03.

Comment: @RichardCritten, it doesn't work over here (Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.36), `clang++ -o test --std=c++03 test.cpp`).

Comment: `template<typename T = void , T* = (T *)0>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no solution to your problem: C++03 pointer template parameters have to designate an object. Using NULL as a non-type template parameter is a feature that was added in [N1905](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf), which came out [at least one year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/251153) after C++03.

> ## 14.3.2 Template non-type arguments
>
> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - an integral constant-expression of integral or enumeration type; or
> - the name of a non-type template-parameter; or
> - the address of an object or function with external linkage, including function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed as & id-expression where the & is optional if the name refers to a function or array, or if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> - **(NEW)** a constant expression that evaluates to a null pointer value (4.10); or
> - **(NEW)** a constant expression that evaluates to a null member pointer value (4.11); or
> - a pointer to member expressed as described in 5.3.1.

One option is to declare a "null struct" with a member that you can use instead of a real `NULL`:

```
template<typename T>
struct null
{
    static T value;
};

template<typename T, T* = &null<T>::value>
struct Foo
{
};
```

Of course, accessing `null<T>::value` has well-defined semantics and it won't crash; the purpose is just to have an address that is guaranteed to be different from the address of any other object.

Note that in any case, it will be impossible for you to use `T = void`. You can't use the `null` workaround with it because `void` is an incomplete type; and you can't cast anything to a `void` pointer to use as a non-type template argument.